# Why does simplyScroll jquery plugin flicker?

Tags: jquery, list, loops, scroll

I'm using a scrolling jquery effect to display logos. Every thing works fine except it flickers and stops sometimes, even in firefox. This leaves a big white gap below the logos for a few seconds, I wonder if its something to do with the loop.

Thanks for your help

Regards

Judi

```
    <div><script src="jquery.simplyscroll-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {  
    $("#brandsScroller").simplyScroll({
            className: 'simplyScroll',
            horizontal: false,
            frameRate: 24,
            speed: 3,
            autoMode: 'loop'
    });

});

</script>
<ul id="brandsScroller">

<li><a href="#" title="#"><img src="studio.gif" alt="#"></a><li><a href="#"><img src="popcorn.gif" alt="#"></a><li><a href="#" title="#"><img src="crafters.gif" alt="#"></a></ul></div>
```

Comment: yep :( is this an imperfection of the plugin?

Comment: I've had this issue too. It's verrrry annoying. Note: this is the simplyScroll plugin, and if you look at simple sites like www.shooterzfc.com you'll see it works fine. This generally only happens  the first time you visit a page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the startOnLoad parameter. This will execute the script only once all the images have loaded and therefore their sizes are known. Alternatively put the image sizes in the img tag.